# android viewmodel observer inside RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder() update every item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, android-viewmodel

I need to download images from AWS S3 and update ImageViews inside a recycler view. I am using ViewModel for downloading files from S3. A file object is observing inside onBindViewHolder() method and once receive the file my intention was to update the image belongs with that particular holder. 
But the problem is if there were two rows, then two images need to download. So each view holder will attach with the observer. After downloading the first file, both the image views inside the recycler view become updated with the first image and after downloading the second image, both images updated with the second image. I am a little bit confuse about working. Please help me with this.
I cannot use **Glide** for this. Because S3 have authentication. So, I need to use S3 library for downloading files.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val postUrl = listData[position].postUrl
        val createdAt = listData[position].createdAt
        val postImage = listData[position].postImage
        val postVideo = listData[position].postVideo
        val postVideoThumbnail = listData[position].postVideoThumbnail
        val groupId = listData[position].groupId
        val postStatus = listData[position].postStatus
        val postId = listData[position].postId
        val userId = listData[position].userId
        val postHeading = listData[position].postHeading
        val postDescription = listData[position].postDescription
        val updatedAt = listData[position].updatedAt
        val profileName = listData[position].userName
        val profileImage = listData[position].profileImage
        val likeCount = listData[position].likeCount
        val commentCount = listData[position].commentCount

        var key = ""

        if(!profileImage.isNullOrEmpty()){
            Glide.with(activity).load(profileImage) to holder.imgProfile
        }
        holder.textName.text = profileName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + profileName.substring(1).toLowerCase()
        holder.textPostedDateTime.text = SimpleDateFormat(POST_LIST_DATE_FORMAT).format(Date(createdAt))
        holder.textPostHeading.text = postHeading
        if(postDescription.isNullOrEmpty() || postDescription == "null"){
            holder.textPostDescription.visibility = View.GONE
        } else{
            holder.textPostDescription.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.textPostDescription.text = postDescription
        }
        if(postUrl.isNullOrEmpty() || postUrl == "null"){
           holder.textPostLink.visibility = View.GONE
        } else{
            holder.textPostLink.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.textPostLink.text = postUrl
        }
        if(postVideoThumbnail.isNullOrEmpty() || postVideoThumbnail == "null"){
            holder.imgPostVideoPreview.visibility = View.GONE
        } else{
            holder.imgPostVideoPreview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            loadImageToFile(holder.imgPostVideoPreview, postVideoThumbnail, position)
            key = postVideoThumbnail
        }
        if(postImage.isNullOrEmpty() || postImage == "null"){
            holder.imgPostImagePreview.visibility = View.GONE
        } else{
            holder.imgPostImagePreview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            loadImageToFile(holder.imgPostImagePreview, postImage, position)
            key = postImage
        }

        holder.textLikeCount.text = likeCount.toString()
        holder.textCommentCount.text = commentCount.toString()
        if(!isSelfPosts){
            holder.layoutCommentLikeShare.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.imgAddComment.setOnClickListener {  }
            holder.imgAddLike.setOnClickListener {  }
            holder.imgShare.setOnClickListener {  }
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            moveTOPostDetails(postId, listData[position], Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/" + EXTERNAL_STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + key.substring(key.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
        }
    }

    class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imgProfile: ImageView = itemView.imgProfile
        val textName: TextView = itemView.textName
        val textPostedDateTime: TextView = itemView.textPostedDateTime
        val textPostHeading: TextView = itemView.textPostHeading
        val textPostDescription: TextView = itemView.textPostDescription
        val textPostLink: TextView = itemView.textPostLink
        val imgPostVideoPreview: ImageView = itemView.imgPostVideoPreview
        val imgPostImagePreview: ImageView = itemView.imgPostImagePreview
        val textCommentCount: TextView = itemView.textCommentCount
        val textLikeCount: TextView = itemView.textLikeCount
        val layoutCommentLikeShare: LinearLayout = itemView.layoutCommentLikeShare
        val imgAddComment: ImageView = itemView.imgAddComment
        val imgAddLike: ImageView = itemView.imgAddLike
        val imgShare: ImageView = itemView.imgShare
    }

    private fun moveTOPostDetails(postId: String, fetchPostsResponseModel: FetchPostsResponseModel, imageFileName: String){
        val intent = Intent(activity, PostDetails::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("POST_DETAILS", fetchPostsResponseModel)
        intent.putExtra("IS_SELF_POST", isSelfPosts)
        intent.putExtra("IMAGE_FILE_NAME", imageFileName)
        activity.startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun loadImageToFile(imageView: ImageView, key: String, position: Int){
        var postListAdapterViewModel: PostListAdapterViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(fragment).get(PostListAdapterViewModel::class.java)

        postListAdapterViewModel.init(activity)

        postListAdapterViewModel.getMediaFile()?.observe(fragment, Observer<File>{ file ->
            var a=position
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file))
        } )
        postListAdapterViewModel.performDownload(key)
    }
```

This is my viewmodel

```
class PostListAdapterViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application){

private val file = MutableLiveData<File>()
private lateinit var context: Context
fun init(context: Context) {
    this.context = context
    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(context).execute()
}
fun performDownload(key : String){
    val credentials = BasicAWSCredentials(AMAZON_S3_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_S3_SECRET_KEY)
    val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials)
    val transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
        .context(context)
        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration)
        .s3Client(s3Client)
        .build()

    val downloadObserver = transferUtility.download (
        key,
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/" + EXTERNAL_STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + key.substring(key.lastIndexOf("/")+1)))

    // Attach a listener to get state updates
    downloadObserver.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {
        override fun onStateChanged(id: Int, state: TransferState) {
            if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                // Handle a completed upload.
                file.value = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/" + EXTERNAL_STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + key.substring(key.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
            }
        }

        override fun onProgressChanged(id: Int, current: Long, total: Long) {
            try {
                val done = (((current.toDouble() / total) * 100.0).toInt()) //as Int
                Log.d("PostListAdapterVM", "DOWNLOAD - - ID: $id, percent done = $done")
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("PostListAdapterVM", "Trouble calculating progress percent", e)
            }
        }

        override fun onError(id: Int, ex: Exception) {
            Log.d("PostListAdapterVM", "DOWNLOAD ERROR - - ID: $id - - EX: ${ex.message.toString()}")
        }
    })

    // If you prefer to poll for the data, instead of attaching a
    // listener, check for the state and progress in the observer.
    if (downloadObserver.state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
        // Handle a completed upload.
    }

    Log.d("PostListAdapterVM", "Bytes Transferrred: ${downloadObserver.bytesTransferred}")
}

fun getMediaFile(): MutableLiveData<File> {
    return file
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your method OnBindViewHolder

Comment: @ToraCode any idea? Could you please help me on this.

Comment: I think  the problem is your viewModel and the observe can call mutliple receive even you split it out. When the image come, it will fire 2 row to update image

Comment: My idea is store the image downloaded to listdata with that position and call `notifyItemChanged(int position)`

Comment: @ToraCode Updated the question with viewmodel

Comment: Did you check my Idea? Everytime your download finished, it will put to the LiveData -> Which will call every observer to update image. No matter how many row you have, you will get the same thing. My Idea is you can change your code in the `Observer` part to store uri File in `listData[position].postImage` plus Uri and call `notifyItemChanged(int position)` to fire `BindViewHolder()` in that position. You will need to change your code in BindViewHolder: When you found you have  `listData[position].postImage` plus Uri , `setImageUri` for imageView

Comment: @ToraCode I'm Sorry, I didn't get you. Could you post this an answer?